# How to resolve custom dependency overrides errors

Tags: maven, maven-3

I get below error in one of my builds.

As per the [this](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/412#issuecomment-919774738)  below failure could be due to corrupted file stored in your local M2 repository, or you have some custom dependency overrides that are not playing well with the plugin.

```
[WARNING] The POM for commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

Rather than deleting the local maven repo folder. is there a other way to fix above kind of issues?

Versions:

```
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 16.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Java\jdk-16.0.2
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

POM: Plugin which cause the issue

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${maven.jmeter.skip}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>configuration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Build Error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.abc.pnv:datagenerator >----------------------
[INFO] Building datagenerator 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ datagenerator ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Repo\PNV\transfers-pnv-java\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ datagenerator ---
[WARNING] The POM for commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 15 resources
[INFO] Copying 20 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ datagenerator ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 84 source files to C:\Repo\PNV\transfers-pnv-java\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/Repo/PNV/transfers-pnv-java/src/main/java/com/abc/pnv/datagenerator/service/modelgenerator/pain/AbstractPaymentModelGenerator.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Repo/PNV/transfers-pnv-java/src/main/java/com/abc/pnv/datagenerator/service/modelgenerator/pain/AbstractPaymentModelGenerator.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jmeter-maven-plugin:3.4.0:configure (configuration) @ datagenerator ---
[INFO]  
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] C O N F I G U R I N G    J M E T E R
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  
[INFO] Creating test configuration for execution ID: configuration
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.951 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-15T16:50:30+10:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:3.4.0:configure (configuration) on project datagenerator: Execution configuration of goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:3.4.0:configure failed: A required class was missing while executing com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:3.4.0:configure: com/jayway/jsonpath/spi/mapper/MappingProvider
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:3.4.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/maven/localRepository/com/lazerycode/jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin/3.4.0/jmeter-maven-plugin-3.4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/maven/localRepository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.MappingProvider
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

**Dependency Tree:**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< com.abs.pnv:datagenerator >----------------------
[INFO] Building datagenerator 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ datagenerator ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] com.abs.pnv:datagenerator:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:jar:3.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.attoparser:attoparser:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.4.2:compile (optional)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.4.2:runtime (optional)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.ibm.mq:mq-jms-spring-boot-starter:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:jar:9.2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.66:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.jms:javax.jms-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json:json:jar:20080701:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.messaginghub:pooled-jms:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_2.0_spec:jar:1.0-alpha-2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.20:compile (optional)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.4.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.2:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.18.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.6.28:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.6.28:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.4.2:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.3.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.zandero.ffpojo:ffpojo-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.joutvhu:fixed-width-parser:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.re2j:re2j:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.26.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.hierynomus:smbj:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.engio:mbassador:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.hierynomus:asn-one:jar:0.4.0:compile
[INFO] \- com.rapid7.client:dcerpc:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO]    \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.830 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-02T19:43:39+10:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is output with `-X`

```
-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution configuration of goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:3.4.0:configure failed: A required class was missing while executing com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:3.4.0:configure: com/jayway/jsonpath/spi/mapper/MappingProvider
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:3.4.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/maven/localRepository/com/lazerycode/jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin/3.4.0/jmeter-maven-plugin-3.4.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/maven/localRepository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:3.4.0:configure: com/jayway/jsonpath/spi/mapper/MappingProvider

-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:3.4.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/maven/localRepository/com/lazerycode/jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin/3.4.0/jmeter-maven-plugin-3.4.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/maven/localRepository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/spi/mapper/MappingProvider
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.doExecute (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:297)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.AbstractJMeterMojo.execute (AbstractJMeterMojo.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.MappingProvider
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.doExecute (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:297)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.AbstractJMeterMojo.execute (AbstractJMeterMojo.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be tested by others. Provide the POM files you have and the `mvn` command you executed. If necessary add the `-X` flag to get more detailed information about the `mvn` execution.

Comment: @Progman Added details into the question.

Comment: @Progman I removed `commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6 ` from local maven repo. But it did downloaded after fresh `mvn clean install `. So is there a way to check which dependency download this `jar `. Because `mvn dependency:tree ` doesn't show `commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6 `. So I assume it is coming via `transitive-dependency `

Comment: It looks like the dependency is used by maven-resources-plugin...where it's needed... @SMPH The output shows all transitive dependencies...

Comment: @khmarbaise Which dependency is used by maven-resources-plugin (i.e. `jmeter-maven-plugin `) and how did you decide that.

Comment: Based on the output: `[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ datagenerator ---
[WARNING] The POM for commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6 is invalid, transiti` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise, How do I know from which transitive dependency that `commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6 `  coming from. Because I don't see it in `mvn dependency:tree `

Comment: As I wrote before it's not from a transitive or dependency of your project its from a plugin...

Comment: @khmarbaise Ah ok sorry, I deleted `commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6 ` and re ran `mvn clean install ` then could see that was downloaded again and that warning disappeared. So the warning could be due to corrupted jar before? However I can see the same build error as specified in the question.

Comment: @khmarbaise Is there a command to get the plugin dependency tree?

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Comment: But you should check why the download of the artifacts is failing or why those artifacts are corrupted...maybe you should turn on checkSum policy... (https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/)